# How to change the ● to ◆ in the given code by using MeshStyle?

Tags: plotting, mesh

I use this code

```
ListPlot[Table[{n, Sin[2 n^2]}, {n, 1, 10}], 
  Frame -> True, 
  Joined -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, LineColor -> LightRed], 
  Mesh -> All, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  Axes -> None]
```

and I get

[image]

Is it possible to change the  `●` to `◆` using `MeshStyle`?

I can get the desired result by

```
ListPlot[Table[{n, Sin[2 n^2]}, {n, 1, 10}], 
 Frame -> True, 
 Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, LineColor -> LightRed], 
 PlotMarkers -> {"◆"}, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 Axes -> None]
```

but this does not help me, since in the domain I need to plot, some undesirable space arises between plot markers and the joined line.

Comment: does this give what you need: `filleddiamond = ChartElementData["FilledMarkers"][[3, 1, 1]];
ListPlot[Table[{n, Sin[2 n^2]}, {n, 1, 10}], Frame -> True, 
 Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, LineColor -> LightRed], 
 PlotMarkers -> {Graphics@filleddiamond, .05}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Axes -> None]`?

Comment: @kglr Yes, thank you very much.

Comment: charmin, posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of a font glyph, you can use a graphics object as plot marker.

`ChartElementData["FilledMarkers"]` gives the list of filled markers:

```
ChartElementData["FilledMarkers"] // Row
```

[image]

The third one is what we need:

```
filleddiamond = ChartElementData["FilledMarkers"][[3, 1, 1]]; 

ListPlot[Table[{n, Sin[2 n^2]}, {n, 1, 10}], Frame -> True, Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, LineColor -> LightRed], 
 PlotMarkers -> {Graphics @ filleddiamond, .05}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Axes -> None]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could just replace points to diamonds:

```
ListPlot[Table[{n, Sin[2 n^2]}, {n, 1, 10}], Frame -> True, 
  Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, LineColor -> LightRed],
   Mesh -> 20, PlotRange -> All, 
  Axes -> None] /. {Point[
    pts_] :> (Inset["◆", #] & /@ pts)}
```